# Fancybox v2.1.4 does not work - $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I just wanted to replace an older version of Fancybox with new v2.1.4. Unfortunately, it does not work. Error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mydomain.com/scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mydomain.com/scripts/fancybox/fancybox.js"></script>

<a class="oforms" href="/my/forms/form.php?id=10">Open form 10</a>
```

Script file:

```
jQuery(function($){$(document).ready(function(){
$(".oforms").fancybox({
'autoDimensions': true,
'transitionIn': 'none',
'transitionOut': 'none',
'onComplete': function() {$("#fancybox-inner").css({'overflow-x':'hidden'});}, 
'ajax' : {
cache : false
}});
..............
..............
})});
```

Comment: Why the first part of the script file? jQuery(function($){

Comment: sorry, I don´t understand your question.

Comment: I don't understand why the jquery(function($) is included in your scriptfile. For all i know it is not needed.

Comment: I don't remember why. It was included many years ago. Do you think it's the reason why new version of Fancybox does not work but old versions is OK?

Comment: the error indicates that there is something wrong with jquery.

Comment: can you verify that the query file is loaded correctly? 

Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309665/fancybox-2-not-working-with-jquery-1-7-2?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planing to upgrade your version, you have to upgrade the API options too. Options in v2.x are new and not compatible with previous versions.

Also you need to specify the `type` of content so try this script (I commented out the old options) :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".oforms").fancybox({
        autoSize: true, // 'autoDimensions': true,
        openEffect: "none", //'transitionIn': 'none',
        closeEffect: "none", // 'transitionOut': 'none',
    // 'onComplete': function() {$("#fancybox-inner").css({'overflow-x':'hidden'});}, 
        afterShow: function () {
            // your function
            // you may not need to mess with overflow, use scrolling instead
        },
        type: "ajax",
        ajax: {
            cache: false
        }
    });
});
```

Check the **[documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)** for the complete set of options for v2.x.